# Hibernate NoSuchMethodError for addPackage method

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, configuration

i use Hibernate for connecting to my db and i configure my database in side of my dbConnector class:

```
public static SessionFactory connectingHibernate(){
    Properties database=new Properties(); 

    database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class",PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER);
    database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",USERNAME);
    database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",PASSWORD);
    database.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url",url);
    database.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",DIALECT);

    Configuration cfg=new Configuration()
            .setProperties(database)
            .addPackage("androidapi.model")
            .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Product.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(PriceProduct.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(CoinPrice.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(SellPage.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Setting.class)
            .addAnnotatedClass(Message.class);



    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(cfg.getProperties());
    sessionFactory=cfg.buildSessionFactory(ssrb.build());
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

when i run my application from inside of my ide my code works correctly but after making war file with maven i got this exception on methods that use my db! how can i fix this?

exception:

```
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "exception": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "message": "org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addPackage(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;",
```

after removeing this line: .`addPackage("androidapi.model")` i got this exception:

```
"exception": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "message": "org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;",
  "path": "/myinsta/admin_api/mGetAllUser"
```

my pom.xml Hibernate dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
```

**solved!** read answer and its good to know that you should use compatible version of hibernate that can find here at meaven part:
[Maven dependency](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/)

Comment: Do you really need this `addPackage("androidapi.model")`?

Comment: yes if i remove this line it cant find my db model classes like User & ... @v.ladynev

Comment: Do you use annotations on `User`?

Comment: Side note (unrelated to the problem): Normally you would not want to use `LATEST` as it makes your builds nondeterministic.

Comment: @raphaëλ you R right !TnQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line

```
addPackage("androidapi.model")
```

The method `addPackage()` doesn't scan a package. It is for reading "package-level metadata" (`.package-info-` files).

Looks like, you use Hibernate 5. You can't use Hibernate 4 configuration code with Hibernate 5

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711654/3405171

If you want to scan packages

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35248061/3405171

To use a valid Hibernate version just check this page with Hibernate core 
versions:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core

and add it to the `pom.xml` (if you use Maven). For example for Hibernate 5.2.1.Final (It uses Java 8):

```
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
  </dependency>
```

A dependency from `hibernate-core` is pretty enough, because of all other libraries will be loaded by Maven as transitive dependences. However, to use logger you need to add an additional dependency.

If you want to download an archive with all required jars, you can check the Hibernate download page:

http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

Comment: "exception": "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
  "message": "org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;",
  "path": "/myinsta/admin_api/mGetAllUser"

Comment: after removeing addpack()

Comment: i removed all of my cached jar files and download all again

Comment: @mehdiakbarian You need to fix your `pom.xml`

Comment: thats the point! how?? my pom.xml works fine when i use my ide to run and debug but when i make war file its doesnt work idk how to fix it

Comment: do you know about config xml file??i use xml instead of that methods and i got another error

Comment: @mehdiakbarian Yes, I know. It will not help you, if you don't fix a previouse error. Because, that error means, that you have incompatible libraries in the classpath.

Comment: yes you R right!can you share your telegram id? i need your help for compatible version

Comment: @mehdiakbarian I don't have it. Just find a valid `pom.xml` for Hibernate. Use Hibernate 5.2 version, for an example.

Comment: thank you i found compatible version please add this to your answer

Comment: @mehdiakbarian You are welcome. Thank you for accepting. I update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple versions of hibernate on your classpath (at the time of this writing this: most likely `3.6.0.beta2` and at `5.2.1.Final`)

Remove:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

This is pulling in an older version.

Comment: Funny, looks like, `hibernate` is an artifact id of an old version of Hibernate :)