# Hibernate Entity Manager - QuerySyntaxException: FooBar is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm getting `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException` when trying to execute a query with EntityManager.

I'm using Hibernate standalone in a Java SE application. I'm not using XML configuration.

This is how I get my session and EntityManager (settings variable is a `Map<String, String>`):

```java
StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
registryBuilder.applySettings(settings);
registry = registryBuilder.build();
MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
EntityManager em = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```

This is my entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "playeraccount")
public class PlayerAccount {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "playerId")
    private String playerId;
    @Column(name = "balance")
    private Double balance;

    [getters, setters...]
}
```

The table SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PlayerAccount (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    playerId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    balance DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0
);
```

And finally the query:

```java
TypedQuery<PlayerAccount> q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM PlayerAccount a WHERE a.playerId = :uuid", PlayerAccount.class);
q.setParameter("uuid", uuid);
PlayerAccount acc = q.getSingleResult();
```

Whole exception is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: PlayerAccount is not mapped [SELECT a FROM PlayerAccount a WHERE a.playerId = :uuid]
```

Comment: is your table name  same?

Comment: your table is called playeraccount, can you try with small case? Select a FROM playeraccount?

Comment: @SusanMustafa same error when it's lowercase.

Comment: The table defined in your entity is small case playeraccount, but you stated create table PlayerAccount .  So change it on your Entitylevel as well, then leave PlayerAccount in your query. @JakeS.

Comment: wait....you didnt map the class?      configuration.addAnnotatedClass(com.xyz.entities.PlayerAccount.class);

Comment: I knew I must've missed something. Which class is this function in? I don't have a "configuration" variable in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be :
"SELECT * FROM playeraccount a WHERE a.playerId = :uuid"

Comment: Still the same exception. It just occurred to me that MySQL table names are not case sensitive on Windows. Could that have an effect?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/ch01.html#setup-requirements

Comment: Follow the above link to use XML configuration file or programmatically to enable your Entity to be picked up by Hibernate for mapping. Also you should let hibernate create the tables for you, rather than running the SQL yourself to avoid any mismatch in the Entity definition and SQL Table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
EntityScanner.scanPackages("my.com.entities", "my.com.other.entities")
    .addTo(configuration);
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

I missed the part about lack of xml :)

or

```
List<Class<?>> classes = EntityScanner
        .scanPackages("my.com.entities", "my.com.other.entities").result();

MetadataSources metadataSources = new MetadataSources();
for (Class<?> annotatedClass : classes) {
    metadataSources.addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass);
}

SessionFactory sessionFactory = metadataSources.buildMetadata()
    .buildSessionFactory();
```

[Can hibernate scan packages to create SessionFactory automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245619/can-hibernate-scan-packages-to-create-sessionfactory-automatically)

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question, I am not using XML configuration.

Comment: @JakeS. can you try the above please.  Map your packages (That have your entities in them)

Answer (score 0):

Use the standard approach to create an `EntityManagerFactory` which is:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PersistenceUnitName", settings)
```

You can cast or unwrap this to a `SessionFactory` if you like. Also, make sure the `persistence.xml` contains the FQN to the entity class. You can also follow the following tutorial if you want to use the Hibernate native APIs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_annotations